# jQuery Add/Remove Class

Tags: jquery, hide, z-index, show

Okay, I thought I would be able to do this no problem, but for some reason I can't figure it out.

I want to have three boxes, with them stacked sort of like cards. Middle box showing on load, the other two behind. Then when the user hovers over one, it's z-index increases and the box goes in front. The boxes will stay in the exact same place that they are on page load, I just want to have them fully appear on hover, which I'm assuming can be done by toggling their z-index.

Here is as far as I've gotten: http://jsfiddle.net/q8nYz/ (I'm just doing on click for now)

```
<div id="#container">

    <div id="box-1" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box-2" class="box active"></div>
    <div id="box-3" class="box"></div>

</div>
```

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
}

.box {
    background: gray;
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

#box-1 {

}

#box-2 {
    left: 200px;
}

#box-3 {
    left: 400px;
}

.active {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```
$(".box").click(function() {

    if ($(".box").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".box").removeClass("active");
    }

});
```

Comment: Have a look here for some ideas: http://usejquery.com/posts/create-a-unique-gallery-by-using-z-index-and-jquery

Comment: @Robert Harvey Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/q8nYz/2/

```
.box:hover{
     z-index: 100;   
}
```

**it only needs css.**

Comment: Awesome, I guess I was over thinking it. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

You just needed to add the `active` class to the box that is clicked, using:

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

I [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/q8nYz/1/).

**EDIT** I like [this idea](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/q8nYz/13/) better. It "moves them back" instead of just moving one to the front. This way it feels more natural (try changing them a lot).

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    $(".box").css("z-index", function() {return $(this).css("z-index") - 1;});
    $(this).css("z-index", 3);
});
```

Comment: Make sure you post your code here. Fiddle links do not count as posted code.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The only problem is, when you click the left and then right box (or vice versa), they both come to front and leave the middle box behind, and it looks funny :)

Answer (score 0):

Two things, z-index needs to be greater than 1 (default is 1). And you need to use `$(this)` instead of `.box` when referencing the clicked item to stop it adding and removing the class from them all.

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/q8nYz/15/

Comment: Make sure you post your code here. Fiddle links do not count as posted code.

Comment: Ahh, good point on the `z-index`. @AndrewMilson covered this with the CSS `:hover` selector.